# Use Flutter foundation types without Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There are three types that are present on the lib 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' that I need to use in an environment without Flutter. They are: `ByteData`, `ReadBuffer` and `WriteBuffer`. Is it possible to use these classes without having the whole Flutter as dependency?

The reason why I need to use it in an environment without Flutter is because I have a server made using Dart and I need to use these classes to encode/decode my socket messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ByteData` is available in `dart:typed_data`.

Comment: Cool. What about the other two types, is it possible to depend only on flutter foundation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want access to classes in `package:flutter/foundation.dart` you can create a new flutter project as normal and remove `runApp()` from `main()` like this:

```
void main() {
 print("This is now a console only program")
  //no runApp(new MaterialApp())
}
```

This code won't start any mobile app and doesn't need an emulator, just a console. I have done some projects only with Dart and you can use all non UI Material Classes, such as `File`, `StringBuffer`...

Note: Remember to add the path for dart in the system environment variables, in my case `D:\APPS\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin`, then you can navigate to your flutter project and type `dart lib/main.dart` in the console to run the code

Comment: Hi, it does not work for me. when `dart lib/main.dart` it says `Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'`

Comment: When developing a console program, you can’t import dart:ui. You shouldn’t need it though. What do you need it for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65914605/use-basic-classes-like-offset-color-in-dart-without-flutter/65937570#65937570