# Use basic classes like `Offset`/`Color` in Dart without Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use those basic classes (such as `Offset`, `Size`, and `Color`), in a pure-`dart` program. I cannot import them in a pure dart project. How can I use them?

Those classes are really fundamental and quite helpful. For example, with `Color` (and `Colors`) the color system can be easily used. So I would appreciate it if I could use them.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668330/use-flutter-foundation-types-without-flutter), but it gives me the following error: `Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'`. I have also tried copying and pasting, but that is a bit ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Well in short, you can't, unless you copy the code from the source class in `package:flutter/material.dart`.

Comment: Hmm that is not an answer :( I have said it in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can't import `dart:ui` in a console program. But you can make a few things if you want to use them:

To use a `Color` class, along with `RgbColor`, `HexColor`, `HslColor`, `XyzColor` and `CielabColor`, you can use the `color` package. You can use it in a cli app by importing the package in the pubspec.yaml file (which you need to manually create)

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: CLI
description: A CLI App
version: 1.0.0
publish_to: 'none'

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  color: 2.1.1     <---
```

main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:color/color.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  Color color = new Color.hex("FFFFFF");
  print(color);   //Should print "ffffff"
}
```

Edit: If you want to use Flutter's `Color` class, copy it into a separate `color.dart` file, as well as `_scaleAlpha()` found in the same file as the `Color` class (`sky_engine\lib\ui\painting.dart`), and `_clampInt()` + `_lerpInt()` (found in `sky_engine\lib\ui\lerp.dart`). Don't forget to `import "dart:math" as math` to this new file. You said it was ugly to just copy, but it is the best you can do if you want to make this compatible with Flutter later. Just change `import "color.dart"` in your `main.dart` file to `import "dart:ui"`

As for `Size` and `Offset`, they are located in (path to flutter) `flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\geometry.dart`. As you've said, copying and pasting is ugly, and looking at the functions I'd say most are not useful for a console app.

Maybe try to implement them yourself by writing these classes from scratch fit for your needs, or by stripping down the original classes in `geometry.dart`. Both classes are quite small if you remove the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I want my dart package to be compatible with Flutter, but the [Color](https://github.com/MichaelFenwick/Color/blob/master/lib/color.dart) you mentioned is actually not the same class as the [Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html) of flutter

Comment: You are right, fixed this mistake + added an alternative solution, marked with an Edit:. You can't import dart:ui because it is part of the Flutter engine, sky engine. It requires a Flutter app to be running

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually what I finally did was to create a `DColor` (D == "for dart") and some extension methods to convert between DColor and Color. since I want the code to be useable for both pure-dart and flutter. thanks all the same